# How to make a singleton smtp client thread-safe in Python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, thread-safety, smtplib

I'm unsure if I'm even asking the correct question, so please bear with me.

I have an Azure Function App that runs python code. It receives a JSON payload, does some transformations, and sends an email.

Everything worked fine until the function started receiving bursts of requests. This caused exceptions:
`smtplib.SMTPDataError: (432, b'4.3.2 Concurrent connections limit exceeded. Visit https://aka.ms/concurrent_sending for more information. [Hostname=xxxxxxxx]')`

I decided to create a singleton for connection client to work around that:

```py
class EmailSingleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls.__login(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            try:
                status = cls._instances[cls].noop()[0]
            except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
                status = -1
            if status != 250:
                log.info("SMTP Client disconnected")
                cls.__login(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def __login(cls, host, port, user, password, timeout):
        log.info("Refreshing SMTP client")
        cls._instances[cls] = super(EmailSingleton, cls).__call__(host=host, port=port, timeout=timeout)
        cls._instances[cls].starttls()
        cls._instances[cls].login(user=user, password=password)

class EmailConnectionClientSingleton(smtplib.SMTP, metaclass=EmailSingleton):
    pass
```

and use it simply by calling:

```py
EmailConnectionClientSingleton(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    timeout=timeout,
    user=user,
    password=password
).send_message(msg)
```

This works fine when requests come one by one, but I get all kinds of fun exceptions when they arrive in bursts:

- `smtplib.SMTPDataError: (503, b'5.5.1 Bad sequence of commands')`
- `smtplib.SMTPDataError: (250, b'2.1.5 Recipient OK')`
- `smtplib.SMTPDataError: (250, b'2.0.0 OK')`
- `smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'recipient@domain.com': (503, b'5.5.1 Bad sequence of commands')}`

It looks like all of the above are caused by handshakes overlapping and responses being out of order. Only about 1/3rd of emails succeed.

How should I approach this problem? Should I even use a singleton client (This tells me I should: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients)? Do I try to make my singleton client thread-safe somehow? Do I create a queue for the send_message calls? Do I create a worker that sends emails from a different function?

I tried using `_lock = threading.Lock()` when creating the client, but that didn't help since the problem appears to be with using the client and not with creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `queue.Queue`:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None
    _lock = Lock()

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            with cls._lock:
                # another thread could have created the instance
                # before we acquired the lock. So check that the
                # instance is still nonexistent.
                if not cls._instance:
                    cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


class QueueSingleton(Queue, metaclass=Singleton):
    pass
```

Instead of sending the email immediately I put it in the queue:

```py
queue = QueueSingleton()
queue.put(msg)
log.info("Email put in the queue")
```

Then I created a new Azure Function that uses the queue to send emails.

```py
queue = QueueSingleton()

while start_time + FUNCTION_MAX_LIFE > datetime.now():
    try:
        msg = queue.get(timeout=300)
        log.info("Got an email to send!")
    except Empty:
        # If we didn't get anything to send during timeout window
        # end the execution and allow TimeTrigger to spawn a new worker
        log.info("No emails to send. Quitting.")
        break

    try:
        email_connection.send_message(msg)
        queue.task_done()
        log.info(f'Email sent: {msg["To"]}')
```

It feels junky but it appears to be working.